# Throw exception in constructor or validate parameters beforehand when creating an object?

Tags: c#, exception

I am expecting an erroneous parameter for an object instantiation to occur every so often.

Should I 
A) Check the parameters first then create the object if valid.
B) Create the object surrounded by a try/catch block & have the constructor throw an exception when invalid.

Is there any reason to choose A or B over the other?

Comment: Checking is better than throwing, exceptions are expensive.

Comment: Exceptions are only expensive if they throw though right? Or am I mistaken? So if it almost never hits then a try-catch could be faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's only a few (one or two) parameters use a [factory pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx) or static method for creation, try to avoid exceptions in constructors.

Alternatively, if there are many (or optional) parameters use the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Additionally you could expose the validate methods, so cautious clients may check first.

Comment: Why avoid exceptions in constructors?

Comment: @Konrad, as per the Ops opening statement _"I am expecting an erroneous parameter for an object instantiation to occur every so often"_ - exceptions are for the unexpected or exceptional case.  The [DotNet guidelines for constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/constructor) state _"DO throw exceptions from instance constructors, if appropriate"_.  I should, perhaps, have emphasized the **try** in _"try to avoid exceptions in constructors"_.  Validation is a cross-cutting, boundary concern, buried in a constructor logic cannot be reused.

Comment: ... if you expect invalid arguments, own the instantiating code and the constructor - then `try-catch` as validation is clearly wrong.  Personally [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) applies; I don't expect an exception from construction (astonished to find constructor does more than set fields) but fail-later at usage - so preferring fail-fast, a static/factory method is favourable. (Side note; in languages _without_ memory management, it's an anti-pattern, as you oft need to catch thrown exception in order to clean up alloc'd resources before rethrow)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another choice you have is to use a parameterless constructor and an initialization method that returns, say, `true` or `false`.

This way:

1. You can re-use the same object multiple times (manually or using an object pool)
2. The validation logic will be encapsulated

So your class could look like this:

```
class Foo
{
    private Bar m_bar;

    public Foo()
    {
        // do nothing here
    }

    public bool Initialize(Bar bar)
    {
        if (bar == null) // validation logic here
            return false;

        m_bar = bar;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Check
{
    private Some getsome;

    public Some GetSome
    {
       get
       {
            return getsome;
       }
       set
       {
           if(value != null)   //or any other logic you want
              getsome = value; //if another logic like value < 10
           else                //you can throw - throw new ArgumentException - for example
              throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
       }
    }

    public Check()
    {

    }

}
```

if you want to pass it in constructor

```
public Check(Some s)
{
   GetSome = s;
}
```

remenber here in contructor GetSome is the public property so you dont miss the checking